# Вынуть значение из getAttribute по клику в элементе, созданном в js

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

Есть div создаваемый в js

```
let divItem = document.createElement('div',);
divItem.className = 'item';
divItem.setAttribute('qqq', '123');
divItem.addEventListener('click', buy);
nameCategory.append(divItem);
```

Как видно, я пытаюсь повесить на него обработчик и атрибут, или датасет с данными, еще не понял. Сам обработчик:

```
function buy(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('qqq'));
}
```

Я получаю undefined. Думаю что дело в чем то типа потери контекста или какие то проблемы со всплытием, и наверное это решилось бы обработчиком на jquery повешенным на body слушающим всплытие - но я не могу использовать jQuery. Что делать?

Comment: если после этого кода в `divItem` добавляется еще что-то, замени `target` на `currentTarget` или `this.getAttribute('qqq')`, возможно ты кликаешь не на `divItem`

Comment: Верно, currentTarget, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Да нет, всё работает. Может нужен текстовый контент или что-то, что покажет, что вы нажимаете именно на тот див?

```js
let nameCategory = document.getElementById('nameCategory');
let divItem = document.createElement('div');
divItem.className = 'item';
divItem.setAttribute('qqq', '123');
divItem.textContent = 222;
divItem.addEventListener('click', buy);
nameCategory.append(divItem);


function buy(e) {    
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('qqq'));
}
```

```html
<div id="nameCategory"></div>
```